# Best Practices for using partials in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, partial

In keeping with the DRY-principle I try to use partials as soon as I am repeating a particular pattern more than once or twice. As a result, some of my views consist of ten or more different partials. I am worried that this might have a negative effect on the overall performance. Some programming books compare the use of partials with the use of methods. So should I use the same rationale to determine when to use them?

**What is the best practice regarding size and quantity of partials in a Rails project?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like your practice already:  Once you've repeated view code twice, refactor it out to a partial.  Tim's right that you can speed it up as necessary *after* it's been profiled and *after* it's been proven necessary.

Here is my one caveat:  If you work with professional designers who handle the views, it may be easier over the long term to have rather repetitive view code.  Some people have a hard time searching through partials and "seeing" how they all fit together.  I've found it easier with those people to let them manage the whole shebang and update more than one file if they need to.  Optimal?  Not to us as programmers, but designers are more often used to seeing most of the HTML in one or three files rather than 20.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Remember the [rules of optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226465/should-i-use-multiplication-or-division/226610#226610)!

If, once your application is complete, your views are too slow, use something like New Relic to find out where the slowdown is occurring. There are a lot of places that might be, but it's unlikely to be in your partials.