# Best Practices for Rails Partials: Reuse versus Cleanliness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I'm trying to decide how much to reuse partials in Rails. I've seen reuse encouraged here:
[Best Practices for using partials in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926761/best-practices-for-using-partials-in-rails)

But the more you reuse, the more you add if-then logic.

For example, I could use the same partial:
- for the "show" action (showing a single model)
- for the "index" action (showing a collection of models)
- for the "form" action
- for the "show" action of an associated model

My rule of thumb here is if-then is okay in moderation, and without any nested if-thens...but I'm curious if there are any best practices here, as I haven't seen it discussed much.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm talking about if/then based on parameters like "is_editable" or "show_author"...not based on calling action like "for_show" or "for_form".

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that the presence of if/else logic that checks for the calling action in a partial is always an antipattern. It just makes code harder to navigate. Also, if the other developer will do modification on your code he/she will most likely put another elsif, accepting your original design choice.  This will lead to eventual maintainability nightmare.

Comment: I didn't mean if/then based on calling action, more like general parameters. I'll clarify the question..