# Is division more expensive than multiplication in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use multiplication or division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226465/should-i-use-multiplication-or-division)
>   [Compare multiplication and division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180143/compare-multiplication-and-division)

Is division more expensive than multiplication in C++?

I am doing optimization and I can turn B/alpha_B into
B*alpha_A, for some comparison reasons. I can choose now
should I go with multiplication or division?

Comment: what has **your** profiling shown you?

Comment: you implement both, measure and see which is faster; *here is a hint, it probably isn't measurable and most likely doesn't really matter, it isn't 1983 anymore!*

Answer (score 10):

This has nothing to do with C++ (or any other language) and everything to do with the underlying processor architecture/implementation.  Division is generally on the order of 10x slower than multiplication on most processor families.

That said, the latency of a divide instruction is rarely the main performance hotspot in a program these days (your mileage may vary, of course).  The place where it makes most sense to replace division with multiplication by the reciprocal is when you're dividing a vector by a constant factor (e.g. vector normalization, scaling, matrix pivoting).  This is also the place where pipeline depth will do the most to mask the `div` instruction latency and memory bandwidth (assuming large vectors) will likely become the throughput limitation.

In short, it's rarely worthwhile to engage in these types of micro-optimizations these days.  Most likely the compiler optimizer will recognize cases where it makes sense to substitute multiplication for division anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I found a source claiming that multiply is faster:

http://simpletonprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/01/assumed-optimization-floating-point.html

The timings for FMUL & FDIV seem to be fairly conclusive, at least for the processors listed.  Other processors may be different, however.  In other words, learn to profile.