# Why do compilers not coerce "n / 2.0" into "n * 0.5" if it's faster?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization, intrinsics

I have always assumed that `num * 0.5f` and `num / 2.0f` were equivalent, since I thought the compiler was smart enough to optimize the division out. So today I decided to test that theory, and what I found out stumped me.

Given the following sample code:

```
float mul(float num) {
    return num * 0.5f;
}

float div(float num) {
    return num / 2.0f;
}
```

both x86-64 clang and gcc produce the following assembly output:

```
mul(float):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        movss   DWORD PTR [rbp-4], xmm0
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        mulss   xmm0, xmm1
        pop     rbp
        ret
div(float):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        movss   DWORD PTR [rbp-4], xmm0
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        divss   xmm0, xmm1
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

which when fed (looped) into the code analyzer available at https://uica.uops.info/ shows us the predicted throughput of 9.0 and 16.0 (skylake) cpu cycles respectively.

**My question is**:
Why does the compiler not coerce the div function to be equivalent to the mul function? Surely having the rhs be a constant value should facilitate it, shouldn't it?

*PS. I also tried out an equivalent example in Rust and the results ended up being 4.0 and 11.0 cpu cycles respectively.*

Comment: Try compiling with optimization enabled.

Comment: Because, contrary to popular (?) belief, every C++ compiler isn't made specifically for your CPU.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/bTox76eYc they are optimized to be equivalent

Comment: @Blindy - huh?  This optimization isn't target-specific, and divisions is much slower than multiplication on all CPUs.  Compilers can (and do) do it in target-independent optimization passes, for divisors whose reciprocal is exactly representable as an IEEE float or double.  (Or for any divisor with `-ffast-math`, rounding the reciprocal to nearest)

Comment: *I thought the compiler was smart enough to optimize the division out.*  Your thinking is correct.  It appears you did not enable compiler optimizations.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) , although Nole chose to post a more specific answer.  There are other Q&As about compilers optimizing division to multiplication or not, but most of them aren't specific to `/ 2.0` which unlike most values has an exactly-representable reciprocal.   [Should I use multiplication or division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/226465) uses that example, but the answers aren't specific to ahead-of-time compiled langs or the power of 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both compilers will come down to the same implementation if you compile with `-O2` optimized.

https://godbolt.org/z/v3dhvGref

[image]